# I installed phpmyadmin but can not access it on kali linux

Tags: apache-http-server, kali-linux, phpmyadmin

For LAMP server, I install apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin. All installations went OK. But localhost/phpmyadmin does not show in browser. Browser shows blank page.

I restarted apache server. But problem not solved. Here is a [screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mWa0.png) of localhost/phpmyadmin:

[image: phpmyadmin page]

How can I solve this problem? In terminal, mysql query is working but in browser it is not showing.

Comment: does phpinfo shows details about phpmyadmin in browser ?

Comment: yes. all is ok. only phpmyadmin not showing

Comment: any hint on apache error.log and access.log ?

Comment: show this error: [Tue Apr 12 13:04:06.851158 2016] [:error] [pid 1648] [client ::1:58068] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/usr/share/php/php-gettext/gettext.inc' (include_path='.') in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/select_lang.lib.php on line 477

Comment: install package php-gettext and check

Comment: Glad to know the issue is fixed and works fine.